# В git bash не работает приложение по имени

Tags: windows, bash

В windows 10, запустил git bash. 
Далее вызываю 
meteor. 
Пишет

> bash: meteor: command not found.

Но если написать

> meteor.bat

То всё работает.

Как сделать так, чтобы meteor вызывался просто по meteor.

Comment: Создать алиас - man alias.

Comment: У тебя какой-то косяк с `%PATHEXT%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash не знает расширений имени файлов, надо задавать полное имя файла как оно есть.
Просто создайте алиас комманды - `alias meteor meteor.bat`